# Book where aliens kidnap and keep a baby as a pet

Tags: story-identification, alien-abduction

I read a book as a kid and I am trying to find it for my nephew. In it, an infant is stolen by aliens and kept as a pet, and the older sibling(s) go on a rescue mission. I don't really remember much else about it.

I must have read it in late elementary school, so probably around 20 years ago. The scene that sticks in my mind is the older children looking through a window and seeing the baby sleeping.

I don't remember the aliens being malicious so much as indifferent.

I've been looking for this for a while, so if anyone can help I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Do you remember roughly when you read it? Rough range of years?

Comment: Could it be Tarzan?

Comment: It must have been late elementary school, so probably around 20 years ago. The scene that sticks in my mind is the older children looking through a window and seeing the baby sleeping.

Comment: Any more detail on the aliens? Substitute with demons and you've got Darren Shan's _The Demon Thief_.

Comment: I definitely see the similarities, but I don't remember the aliens being malicious so much as indifferent

Comment: The idea of infants being stolen by fairies or other supernatural beings is common in folklore. Often a non-human child is left in its place, known as a [changeling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Changeling). It would not be surprising if there are many science fiction and fantasy stories that pick up on this theme.